# DataTables initialization not returning object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
var table = $("#products-to-add-table").DataTable(table_options);
```

This is supposed to return the datatables object, but I get a blank array in the table variable, even though the table gets initialized and I can see it rendered on my web page
datatables reference: https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ - "The result from each is an instance of the DataTables API object which has the tables found by the selector in its context. It is important to note the difference between $( selector ).DataTable() and $( selector ).dataTable(). The former returns a DataTables API instance, while the latter returns a jQuery object." So try using API methods on it, not sure `table` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: but I'm getting a blank array `[]` assigned to table

Comment: dataTable() does return a jquery object, but DataTable() is returning `[]`, I want to get an API instance

Comment: I don't understand what the DataTable function is for. I can access the api as `table.api` is I use `dataTable()` for initialization

Comment: have you tried without options? I suspect you should be doing `$("#products-to-add-table").dataTable(table_options).api()` to get the API object you're expecting.

Comment: seems like DataTables toString method is messed up, so the chrome console showed `[]`, even though an object was getting returned (a first for me). So..consider this question closed., should I delete it?